# Subsonic 3.0 Query limit with MySQL c#.net LinQ

Tags: mysql, linq, subsonic3, limit

a quick question which may or may not be easily answered.

Currently, in order to return a limited result set of data to my calling reference using SubSonic I use a similar function as below:

```
_DataSet = from CatSet in t2_aspnet_shopping_item_category.All()
                        join CatProdAssignedLink in t2_aspnet_shopping_link_categoryproduct.All() on CatSet.CategoryID equals CatProdAssignedLink.CategoryID
                        join ProdSet in t2_aspnet_shopping_item_product.All() on CatProdAssignedLink.ProductID equals ProdSet.ProductID
                        where ProdSet.ProductID == __ProductID
                        orderby CatProdAssignedLink.LinkID ascending                            
                        select CatSet;
```

and select the first item from the data set.

Is there a way to limit the lookup initially to a certain amount of rows? I'm using MySQL as the base database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using following:

**Using SubSonic:**

If you want to get limited records from subsonic function then you can use `GetPaged` method to get records. To learn more about querying [**visit this link**](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord).

Use `GetPaged` instead of `GetAll` function in your query.

**Using LINQ**

Use `Skip` and `Take` methods to get limited records. To learn more about linq [**visit this link**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).